# How to get username and email from LDAP server in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap

I want to fetch username and email dynamically in Python, as different person executes the code on different PC, code has to work for everyone without asking anything, I mean program should be generic.

Can anyone help in getting details of the user without providing the password?

Answer (score 2):

If your environment allows anonymous binds, you can do that.  eg.

```
import ldap
conn = ldap.initialize("ldap://{}".format(serverName), trace_level=0)
conn.simple_bind_s('','')
```

But most environments I work with won't allow you to search for users after an anonymous bind.  It's a big security risk.  So your best bet (if allowed) is to have a low-access service account (ie. one with only read-only access) to use to do the initial bind and query, and then you can re-bind as that user once found (if you need that.)